# How to get id of the tweet posted in tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to check if a certain tweet is a reply to the tweet that I sent. Here is how I think I can do it:

Step1: Post a tweet and store id of posted tweet

Step2: Listen to my handle and collect all the tweets that have my handle in it

Step3: Use `tweet.in_reply_to_status_id` to see if tweet is reply to the stored id

In this logic, I am not sure how to get the status id of the tweet that I am posting in step 1. Is there a way I can get it? If not, is there another way in which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What one could do, is get the last nth tweet from a user, and then get the tweet.id of the relevant tweet. This can be done doing:

`latestTweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'user', count = n, include_rts = False)`

I, however, doubt that it is the most efficient way.

Comment: This is not clear to me. How do I come to know if the selected tweet is a reply to one particular tweet sent by me. How do I get the id of the tweet that I am posting?

Comment: Since you wrote the original tweet, you know its content. You could thus get the latest tweets, find the one of which the content matches, and obtain its id. From there, you can do your aforementioned step 3.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the `update_status` method of your `tweepy.API` object, it returns a `Status` object. This object contains all of the information about your tweet.

Example:

```
my_tweet_ids = list()

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Post to twitter
status = api.update_status(status='Testing out my Twitter')

# Append this tweet's id to my list of tweets
my_tweet_ids.append(status.id)
```

Then you can just iterate over the list using `for each tweet_id in my_tweet_ids` and check the number of replies for each one.

Comment: status = api.update_status(status='Testing out my Twitter')

+

api.update_status(status="Response 123", in_reply_to_status_id=status.id, auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)

is an excellent solution (Tweepy version 3)